# how to write a rake task to bundle install then rake db:migrate then rake db:seed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

How to write a rake task that will bundle install then rake db:migrate then rake db:seed.

```
namespace 'install' do
  'bundle install'
  'rake db:migrate'
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work but consider using Capistrano/Chef for deployment:

```
namespace :install do
  task :db_reset do
    # bundle install - I do not believe attempting this in a rake file
    # is recommended as one would need to ensure it is run in your application
    # directory and rvm has loaded correct version of ruby/gemsets (.rvmrc required)
    Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
  end
end
```

alternatively, you can setup a shell alias to do

```
bundle install && bundle exec rake db:migrate && bundle exec rake db:seed
```